# Randomized and nonrandomized statistical tests

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I've been reading recently about randomized and non-randomized statistical tests and their differences. If I understand the definition correctly, a nonrandomized test for all values of the test statistics rejects the null hypothesis with probability $1$ or $0$. For a randomized test, for certain values of the test statistics, the probability of rejecting $H_0$ is different from $0$ and different from $1$.

An example of such a randomized test is the exact test for the probability of success from the binomial distribution (binom test, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test). If I understand correctly, the asymptotic test written on Wikipedia is already non-randomized.

I am also considering the definition of the test power function. The version I knew before was just 1 minus type II error. Now, I read that this is a function of the tested $\theta$ parameter and is defined as the expected value $\phi(X)$, where $\phi$ is our statistical test, i.e. a function describing the probability of rejection of $H_0$, which is a function of the random variable $X$ that we are examining. In the case of a non-randomized test, $\phi(X)$ takes only the values $0$ or $1$, so the power function of the test is equal to the type I error when $\theta = \theta_0$ and 1 - type II error when $\theta\neq\theta_0$. If I understand correctly, for a randomized test it is not necessary that the power of the test = type I error or 1-type II error, because with non-zero probability the function $\phi(X)$ takes values other than 0 and 1.

Do I understand all this correctly?

Therefore, if in the simulation task, I should compare the powers of the binom test and the asymptotic test for different values of $\theta$, it is probably not enough in the case of binom test to examine the type 1-type II error for various alternatives? i.e. simulate data not fulfilling $H_0$ and checking how many times $H_0$ was rejected in favor of $H_1$. This will not be the power of the test in the case of randomized test, if I correctly understand the exact definition.

Comment: Do you have a specific, focused question about these topics?  Our goal is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, in the format of questions and answers.  As such, "here are a bunch of statements about my understanding, is all that correct?" is not a great fit, because it is not focused enough, and it is unlikely that anyone else has exactly the same question you have.